# How to get total of top 10 With TIES sales in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am taking `Top 10` of Sales Volume grouped by Product categories in SSRS 2012. I need the total of these top 10 but it shows the complete total.

For this I have used running value inside group and Written hidden expression below. This absolutely working for `top 10 rows and rows less than 10`.. In my report searching based on TaxID..So there may be chance of total sum ties..! so that case this condition is failing

Note: This is condition working for top 10 rows and also rows less than 10...but only failing rows more than 10 rows means top sales ties.( `If 10th and 11th category sales are same those are pulling up into report..but sum is making problem for me`)

```
=IIf(RunningValue(Fields!grp.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing) = 10
or (RunningValue(Fields!grp.Value, CountDistinct, Nothing) = CountDistinct(Fields!grp.Value, "DataSet1") and CountDistinct(Fields!grp.Value, "DataSet1") < 10)
, false
, true)
```

I can't do it on dataset level as I need the complete dataset for other parts in the report. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would solve this by creating a second data set just to return these totals.

Comment: Or by using the RANK() function in SQL server to add a running total in the original dataset.